# Ubuntu-Java Installation-Topcoder-“Java not found”

Tags: java

I realized that this might be the dumbest question here, but being a total beginner as I am, I really couldn't figure it out after trying all kinds of instructions I could found on the web.

**Specs:** Ubuntu 13.04;

**What I intended to do:** check out the Algorithm Competition section, by clicking the second-to-left tab,located on the top-left of the page: http://community.topcoder.com/tc

**What I got:** a pop-up saying

> Java not found! Java could not be automatically detected on your
>   machine. This page will attempt to automatically install Java and Java
>   Web Start. If the download and installation does not occur
>   automatically, click the link below to go to the Sun website where you
>   can download the latest version of Java.

**What I did:** I followed instructions on this Ubuntu Documentation page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java and installed OpenJDK(Java Runtime Environment/Browser plugin/SDK) through Ubuntu Software Center. Then I rebooted the system, tried the page again. But I still got the java not found pop-up described above.

**Question:** What's missing the get this working? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should download the last version of java"7" and fellow this steps:

1. First of all extract the file : `tar -xvf ~/Folder`
2. Create jvm directory on /usr/lib :  `sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0`
3. Copy the file into home folder to jvm/jdk.. : `sudo mv jdk1.7.0_09/* /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/`
4. Create repository for the java : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`
5. Update all packages on your ubuntu : `sudo apt-get update`
6. Get the java update : `sudo apt-get install update-java`
7. Update java : `sudo update-java`
8. Check the version : `java -version`

If it's checked and it show you the version your java is well installed!